# How to transform jsonb object to an array of objects?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

From this:

```
 "data": {
           "media_object_uuid": ["5171167e-c109-4926-9606-5212ee250e2f"]
         }
```

to this:

```
        "data": {
                  "media_object":[{"media_object_uuid": "5171167e-c109-4926-9606-5212ee250e2f"]
                }
```

In words, I want to extract the first value of this array and set it on the new field media_object_uuid inside media_object. My approach to resolve this was:

```
update demo_test set data = jsonb_set(data,'{media_object_uuid}',('{"media_object": { "media_object_uuid":' || (data->"media_object_uuid"[0])::text || '}}'));
```

But I have in return media_object_uuid column doesn't exist

Comment: What are you using this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to call `data->"media_object_uuid"` as `data->'media_oject_uuid'`, since in Postgres, double-quotes are used to refer to column/entity names (unless they are first encapsulated in single-quotes):

```
edb=# create table abc (data jsonb);
CREATE TABLE
edb=# insert into abc values ('{
edb'#            "media_object_uuid": ["5171167e-c109-4926-9606-5212ee250e2f"]
edb'#          }');
INSERT 0 1
edb=# select ('{"media_object": [{ "media_object_uuid":' || (data->'media_object_uuid')::text || '}]}') from abc;
                                      ?column?                                       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"media_object": [{ "media_object_uuid":["5171167e-c109-4926-9606-5212ee250e2f"]}]}
(1 row)

edb=# update abc set data = jsonb_set(data,'{media_object_uuid}', ('{"media_object": [{ "media_object_uuid":' || (data->'media_object_uuid')::text || '}]}')::jsonb);
UPDATE 1
edb=# select * from abc;
                                                    data                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"media_object_uuid": {"media_object": [{"media_object_uuid": ["5171167e-c109-4926-9606-5212ee250e2f"]}]}}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Indeed, I was lacking the single quote on data->'media_object_uuid' and '::jsonb' at the end of the sentence.